# Secure Google Redirect URL

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I enabled Google Login option in website from where I get UserInfo and Email. I am using **Google APIs Client Library for PHP**.

I set redirect URL to

```
$client->setRedirectUri('http://login.example.com/authenticate/redirect_back');
```

and same in Google Developers Console. So after successful user login Google redirect back to

http://login.example.com/authenticate/redirect_back?code=4/gdtpUtOQ3ThblOTVnhEOtoeoeNRa.AqLKJLKDJxy_bnfDxpKmSx6cjgI

now my question is "What if somebody intentionally create `code=4/xzzzz`?" because Google openly showing where it is going to redirect (see in screenshot link | sorry i cannot post with < 10 reputation).

[Google Auth Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDaVB.png)

I tried myself with dummy value and it get authenticated. But throws fatal error with `invalid_grant` when getting UserInfo. Is there a way to validate code value just after Google redirect back?

Comment: Could you explain how does the auth work for you? The flow is not clear. How do you get userInfo and Email. I suppose that is by using the code in the redirect. Just confirm this for me..

Comment: @SambhavSharma, here is the example http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not need to secure the Google Redirect URL.

Because the flow of authentication clearly says that,

`once user grants the basic permission to access their data, user is redirected back to your website with Authentication code. The code is used to obtain Access Token, using Access Token the application can access current user data from Google, which could be used to register and login the user.`

So in case a user tries to hit the callback URL with any arbitrary code, Google will not be able to authenticate the user and provide you with an  `User Info` and `email` . Hence, you will not be able to register/login the user.

Comment: thing is it provides `Access Token`, because it is not checking to google server while providing access token. but once i request userinfo, it make request to server with invalid access token and throws fatal error.... i want to validate the access token or code before fatal error.

Comment: what you need to do is some sort of error/exception handling in your code. Google will never tell you how to validate an access token on your local server. Hope it clears the problem..